# Overriding terminal width in Mercurial command

Tags: 14.04, mercurial

Some Mercurial commands format output differently depending on the width of the terminal. This is convenient when I just need to look at the output, but very inconvenient when the output is not sent to the terminal but rather to a pipe or a file.

Is there some way in which I can override the terminal width and get Mercurial to format the output optimized for a width which I specify on the command line?

Here is an example of the problem I am having:

```
$ hg log --stat -r 4210 | wc
     10      37     375
$ hg log --stat -r 4210 | wc
     10      37     375
$ hg log --stat -r 4210 | wc
     10      37     512
$ hg log --stat -r 4210 | wc
     10      37     512
$
```

I changed the size of the window midway through this sequence of commands, and Mercurial started producing different output. What I would like is something like this:

```
$ hg log --width 79 --stat -r 4210 | wc
     10      37     374
$
```

Where I can somehow specify that I want the output formatted as if the terminal was 79 characters wide, regardless of the actual width of the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function can be found in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/ui.py`:

```
def termwidth(self):
    '''how wide is the terminal in columns?
    '''
    if 'COLUMNS' in os.environ:
        try:
            return int(os.environ['COLUMNS'])
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return util.termwidth()
```

From this it is clear that the answer is to simply write `COLUMNS=79` in front of the `hg` command to achieve the desired result:

```
$ COLUMNS=79 hg log --stat -r 4210 | wc
     10      37     374
```